# What is fminsearch's time complexity?

Tags: matlab, time-complexity

The [`fminsearch()` function description](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html) is as follows:

> Nonlinear programming solver. Searches for the minimum of a problem
> specified by
>
> min x f(x)
>
> f(x) is a function that returns a scalar, and x is a vector or a
> matrix.

What is its Big O time complexity?

Comment: I don't think big O notation makes sense for optimization algorithms that have relative stopping criteria. The algorithm will be more influenced by the shape of `f(x)` rather than the size of `x`. But here is the algorithm if you want to try to figure out: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/optimizing-nonlinear-functions.html#bsgpq6p-11

Comment: I see, thanks for answering my doubts